# How to Create Table Dependecy Tree - Oracle

Tags: oracle, dependencies

Given an Oracle table, how can I found out what depends on that table?  e.g. Which Views, Functions, Stored Procs, etc.

One would think it would be easy given Oracle SQL Developer or Aqua Data Studio, but they don't contain that feature. How frustrating!

Comment: Look at the ALL_DEPENDENCIES view.

Comment: I did; When I query the that table, I only get one row back. 

SELECT * FROM all_dependencies
WHERE referenced_name like '%MyViewName%'

For the life of me, I cannot understand why ORACLE makes it so hard to understand the dependency of things.  

Note It is really easy in SQL Server.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190624.aspx

Comment: This will only show objects in the current schema.  If you need to look across schemas, then you need to use DBA_DEPENDENCIES.  You know it is case-sensitive also?  All the values are in uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aqua Data Studio, connect to your Oracle Server and Expand your Tables node under the Schema Browser. Pick your table, right click and select Table Properties. Navigate to the Dependencies tab and you can see all the dependencies.
[image] 
 
[image]

Comment: Table Properties works!  The Dependencies tab contains both the "depend on a table" and "objects on which a table depends" lists.

Note: The treeview does contain a Dependencies node for a table, but it does not contains all of the items in the properties dependencies list. e.g. Missing Index, Trigger, etc